# How can I create location request in Android? "LocationRequest.create()" is deprecated now

Tags: java, android, android-location

LocationRequest.create()
"This method is deprecated. Use LocationRequest.Builder instead." says in documentation. But I don't no how to use it.

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I want to change location settings programmaticaly, so I need the variable locationRequest. Can anyone help me to create the variabel locationRequest.
I use Java as programming language.

Comment: There is a link in the documentation how to use LocationRequest.Builder: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.Builder

Answer (score 3):

```java
LocationRequest locationRequest = 
 new LocationRequest.Builder(
  LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY,
  10000
 ).build();

locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
```

Comment: gracias  me ayudo mucho

Answer (score 0):

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest.Builder(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, 100)
                .setIntervalMillis(INTERVAL_MILLIS)             // Sets the interval for location updates
                .setMinUpdateIntervalMillis(INTERVAL_MILLIS/2)  // Sets the fastest allowed interval of location updates.
                .setWaitForAccurateLocation(false)              // Want Accurate location updates make it true or you get approximate updates
                .setMaxUpdateDelayMillis(100)                   // Sets the longest a location update may be delayed.
                .build();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).